# Setting layout_width, layout_height using a style

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I used a style file to set a unique style for same layouts,

Style:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- User form layout style -->
   <style name="UserFormLayoutRow">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/padding_small</item>
   </style>
</resources >
```

//In layout file

```
 <LinearLayout
   style="@style/UserFormLayoutRow" >
         //contents
 </LinearLayout>
```

`Error:(design time)`

[image]

Error at run time:

`06-13 05:58:14.506: E/AndroidRuntime(936): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #105: You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

Where i am going wrong? TIA

Comment: you should specify the linear layout width and height.i guess you have not done that

Comment: @ Raghunandan i specified it in style file right? i dnt like to again writing same thing..Assume hve hundred linear layout,  so i want to put it in style file and get it from there?

Comment: What's your min and target SDK version in manifest?

Comment: The same works for me are you sure the line #105 have the same LinearLayout ?

Comment: Do you just have it defined in the `res\values` folder, but not in the `values-v11` and `values-v14` folders? You might try to define them in those 2 folders as well according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947720/android-theme-not-being-set?lq=1) question.

Comment: @ laalto   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: @Shobhit Puri still no luck

Comment: Only some other minor issues seen here that do not cause this behavior: `LinearLayout` close tag missing, `//` is not a valid comment for xml, `xmlns:android` is not needed for `values` resources. So, since what you posted works for others, there's something missing from the question.

Comment: Go through with this link
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497758/why-shouldnt-i-set-layout-width-and-layout-height-in-a-style/34761308#34761308)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** I checked for your scenario. It appears that layout_width and layout_height must be given defined under layout. If you do not want to mention them in xml, then mention it in style.xml and use it for your view.

Comment: can you please refer me a official link on this

Comment: @RajaJawahar, I am facing a problem, when I apply layout_width and layout_height using styles.xml and above mentioned styles not applying in view.Can you provide some sample code or where am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Even i had this same problem, the way i solved is just provide **wrap_content to both height and width in the layout xml file**. Then **override whatever height and width you want in the style xml file**, so now you need not change the value again in layout xml file. At last just add the style attribute to the corresponding view.